# C++ Multiple Classes in ONE cpp file

Tags: c++, class, object, identifier, specifier

I'm required to work with multiple classes in one `.cpp` file. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, is there a header file I need to include?

These are the errors I'm getting:

```
error C3646: 'loginObject': unknown override specifier

error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

error C2065: 'loginObject': undeclared identifier
```

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

//Declaration of Class that Allows User to Select a Menu Option
class Menu
{
private:
    int userChoice = 0; //User's Menu Selection

    //Class Objects
    Login loginObject;

public:
    void options()
    {
        //Loop of Initial Menu
        do
        {
            //Startup Menu
            cout << "\n\tMain Menu:"
                "\n\n\t1. Login"
                "\n\t2. Create Password"
                "\n\t3. Change Password"
                "\n\t4. Delete User"
                "\n\t5. Exit"
                "\n\nSelection: ";
            cin >> userChoice;
            cout << endl;

            //Switch Statement that Determines Course of Action based upon User's Choice
            switch (userChoice)
            {
            case 1:
                loginObject.login();    //Option to Login
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "\nCreating Password...";  //Option to Create a New Password
                cout << endl;
                break;
            case 3:
                cout << "Changing Password...";  //Option to Change an Old Password
                cout << endl;
                break;
            case 4:
                cout << "Deleting User..."; //Option to Delete a User
                cout << endl;
                break;
            case 5:
                cout << "Exiting...";   //Option to Exit the Program
                cout << endl << endl;
                system("pause");
            default:
                cout << "INVALID MENU OPTION!\n";
                break;
            }

        } while (userChoice != 5); //Loop to Return to Initial Menu
    }
};

//Declaration of Class that Manages all Activities Dealing with Login
class Login
{
private:

public:
    void login()
    {
        cout << "\nLogging In...";
        cout << endl;
    }
};

//Main File
int main()
{
    //Call to Menu Class 
    Menu menuVariable;
    menuVariable.options();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Mind if I ask what compiler you're using? Those are some pretty crummy error messages. gcc gives me the much more helpful (and correct) "error: ‘Login’ does not name a type". Is it an old compiler?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio

Comment: And not looking at the full error messages, just a summary.

Comment: Not clear it's the source of the message you're seeing, but having `class login` contain a function named `login` that attempts to return `void` is a problem--a function with the same name as its containing class is a constructor, for which you're not allowed to specify a return type.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, your C++ code is read from top to bottom. So you can't use the name `Login` before it's defined. In your case, you can just move `Login` to above `Menu` (since the former does not depend on the latter) and it'll all be fine. In general, you can write a *prototype* at the top of your file to indicate the shape of a class without showing its implementation. So, for `Login`, that would be

```
class Login {
public:
    void login(); // Note: No function body
};
```

Comment: WOW i'm so over myself.

Comment: I moved the login class to above the menu class and it worked, thanks for that clarification Silvio

Comment: But also note that `login::login` has to be a ctor, which can't specify a return type.

Comment: @JerryCoffin That function doesn't look like a constructor to me. Its implementation prints some text out and (presumably) changes some internal state. At no point does it attempt to construct an instance of `Login`.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo: true--but since it's named `login` and its contained in a class named `login`, it can't possibly be anything else. A member function named the same as the class  that contains it must always be a constructor.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Check the capitalization on both. In both OP's code and mine, it's a method named `login` in a class called `Login` (keeping with the way C++ programmers typically name classes), and such a method is perfectly cromulent. Normally, I might object to having such similar names for a class and a function, but "login" in English is both a noun and a verb. I can have a `Login` (i.e. my user account), to which I attempt to `login` (meaning provide authentication details for), so this seems like a legitimate naming scheme to me.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo: ah, good point on capitalization--my mistake. I'm less convinced by the argument in favor of the naming though. If `Login` is intended to mean `UserAccount`, then `UserAccount` would be a much better name for it.